# Sort command is printing in unordered sequence in linux terminal

Tags: linux

I have one file named **temp** following are the data in the file

```
0.9
1
2
3
10
4
5
6
```

When i am execute **sort temp** in the terminal i am getting the answer as

```
0.9
1
10
2
3
4
5
```

But my expected answer is

```
0.9
1
2
3
4
5
10
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `man sort`:

```
  -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

Thus, use

```
sort -n temp
```

Answer (score 1):

The command sort by "dictionary-order" by default

If you want to order numerically use `-n`

```
sort -n file
```

Comment: I understood and Thanks.